# What happened to Adroit Technologies and their licensed VB6 SmartTabs and OutlookBar controls?

Tags: vb6, vb6-migration

I've inherited a VB6 project from about 6-8 years ago. It uses SmartTabs and Smart OutlookBar, two licensed controls from Adroit Technologies that were shipped (in trial versions) with the original VB6.

Without licensing the controls I can't compile or debug the project, and although I've got the old license details, the license is tied to a specific development machine so they won't work for me (the original development machine has long since gone).

Adroit Technologies (AdroitTech.in) seems to have dropped off the radar, their contact details don't work and searches don't turn up anything.

Any ideas folks on how to get round this license issue?

Mike

Update: I've managed to edit the source code to eliminate the need for the SmartTabs control ... that just leaves the OutlookBar one to sort out!

I've now found another control in the project which has the same issues. This time called XE-Date and again from a defunct company. However, this one is relatively easy to replace using a mixture of standard controls.

Comment: Are you sure it's written in VB6 not VB.Net? Vb6 was last sold well over 20 years ago and I can't recall it ever being shipped with those controls, even trial versions. The company still seems to exist: https://www.adroit-europe.com/  but whether they'd be able to help is another matter entirely!

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment and information ... it's definitely VB6, absolutely definitely VB6! And yep, it's really ancient!

I'll check the adroit-europe.com link to see if that's them, could be a life saver if it is!

Comment: The controls were brought in with Service Pack 6 (I think) ... it was a bit naughty really as it wasn't obvious that they were trial versions. Folk started using them and then later found out that the trial period had expired and they had to either pay up or revisit their work and edit it out again.

Comment: Service packs 5 & 6 were purely executables on the Microsoft web site. I have SP6 here and there are certainly no extra non-Microsoft controls with it. Anyhow good luck with contacting them!

Comment: Umm .. just shows how unreliable my memory can be over the 15-20 year time period! ... I contacted Adroit-Europe ... sadly it's not their stuff, they knew of Adroit Technologies (India) because of the shared name. They're having a collective head scratch to see if anyone can remember what happened to the other company. Fingers crossed it leads somewhere!

Comment: Maybe it depended on the edition of VB6 whether these were included? I don't have anything labeled Adroit in my VB6 installation.  What are the OCX/DLL files that correspond to these controls?

Comment: If nothing else, [vbAccelerator's ListBar Control](https://www.vbaccelerator.com/codelib/listbar/listbar.htm) might be a replacement, also mimicking The Outlook  Bar of old. Ofc this would require rewriting those parts of your project.

Comment: I also don't have these controls with Enterprise Edition.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/Planet-Source-Code/vlad-vissoultchev-double-dragon-outlook-bar-control-photoshop-style-color-picker-now-witho__1-36529) is a legacy open source OutlookBar control that’s been ripped by several indian companies in the past.